# populate Jstree from xml string with checkbox

Tags: jquery, xml, jstree

Hi guys i have "xmlstring" this string comes from database. I need to populate jstree using this string with check box plug ins and when i select check boxes it should not return check box text but it should return Attribute "ID" associated with selected XML tags. User see only element value. ID within attribute should be hidden. its really complicated. and i m stuck for many days. Any kind of help is appreciated.. My XML elements in XML are like this:

```
<PG id="123">ABC</PG>
```

.i m using c#.net

Comment: at client or server?  more detail on what you need would help

Comment: So you need a function that is triggered on a jsTree checkbox click? If yes, then add the ID to the node as extra attribute and in the checkbox click function do with this ID what ever needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Checkbox plugin and then use only the id part of the objects returned:

```
 var checked = $("#your_tree_id").jstree("get_checked",null,true);
 $(checked).each(function (i,node) {
     var id = $(node).attr("id");
     // do something with id
 }
```